# actionscript facebook get url of uploaded image

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, actionscript

using the latest facebook actionscript library, I upload an image using:

Facebook.api('me/photos', etc...)

it returns an ID, which method would I call to get the url of the uploaded image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a simple REST service call:  https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729

Take a look at the "Example" at the bottom of this page:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/